# Safe secure way to locate a file in FreeBSD?

Tags: files, freebsd, locate

In [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) 12, on a freshly-created [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) ([DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean)), I tried to use the [`locate`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=locate&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) command.

```zsh
$ locate java
```

I received an error.

> locate: database too small: /var/db/locate.database
>
> Run /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb

So I ran `locate.updatedb`.

```zsh
$ /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

Got a message, complaining about permissions.

> /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb: cannot create /var/db/locate.database: Permission denied

Okay. Run as sudo.

```zsh
$ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

I got a security warning.

> > > > WARNING
> > > >
> > > > Executing updatedb as root.  This WILL reveal all filenames
> > > >
> > > > on your machine to all login users, which is a security risk.

Unix is so much fun.

➥ What is the proper secure way to find a file or directory by name on your FreeBSD system?

Comment: Related Question: [*Delete the “locate” database in FreeBSD*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531770/56752)

Comment: The `locate` command has its database updated only daily or weekly. That is why you get the "too small" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`locate` is an easy way to search for a file quickly since it has it's own database. However, I always just use [`find(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html). The results are returned to the user who ran it, and the user who ran it can only find files they have the appropriate file system permissions to.

`find` searches recursively, so you can specify `/` as the search path if you want to search every filesystem.

Finding all files and directories named `foo`:

```
find / -name "foo"
```

Finding *only* files named `foo`:

```
find / -type f -name "foo"
```

Finding *only* directories named `foo`:

```
find / -type d -name "foo"
```

There are a lot of useful options. Check out the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: Also, `find` doesn't require a database, so its answers will always be up to date, modulo any changes that may occur while `find` is running.

Answer (score 3):

## `run periodic`

As you have learned, the [`locate`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=locate&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) command uses a database storing an indexed collection of your file and folder names. Because your installation of FreeBSD is brand-new, that database has not yet been built.

When will the database be built? When FreeBSD performs its regular housekeeping chores. There are batches of such chores to be done automatically on a daily, weekly, and monthly basis. See the [`periodic`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=periodic&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) command.

You may want to perform those housekeeping chores immediately, after creating your virtual machine. Run:

```zsh
periodic daily
periodic weekly
periodic monthly
```

Or run all three in one line.

```
periodic daily weekly monthly
```

In my experience, these take about a minute each.

➥ In particular, the `weekly` one seems to create/update the `locate` database. When you cannot find something you know exists, do `run periodic weekly`.

If curious, you could check the existence and size of your `locate` database before and after running `periodic`. Likely found here: `/var/db/locate.database`

You should now be able to use the `locate` command successfully.