# Delete the "locate" database in FreeBSD

Tags: security, freebsd, locate

After having established the [`locate`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=locate&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) command's database indexing file & directory names across my FreeBSD 12 system (as described in [this related Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531754/56752)), I now regret doing so because of its emitted security warning:

> Executing updatedb as root. This WILL reveal all filenames on your machine to all login users, which is a security risk.

➥ Is there a way to undo the effects of running `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`?

Comment: Not knowing BSD, I would see if there is a port of `slocate` or `mlocate` available, which hide files from users if they don't have permission to view them.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Thanks, but neither of those are bundled with FreeBSD 12, and neither are found in the Packages tree. [This Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531756/56752) suggests using `find` as a secure but slower alternative to `locate`.

Comment: You could run `sudo periodic weekly` to build/rebuild the locate database safely .

Comment: @fd0 Thanks for that valuable info! I [added that as an Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532145/56752) on [my other related Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531754/56752).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that [`locate.updatedb`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=locate.updatedb) does is update the locate database.

If you don't want to divulge the locations of sensitive files via that database, then you can wait for `locate.updatedb` to complete, and then run the `rm` command to remove the database:

```
sudo rm /var/db/locate.database
```